# Weblogic 12.2.1 upgrade domain reconfigure.sh.

Tags: weblogic12c

I need to upgrade a weblogic domain to 12.2.1 from 12.1.3.  I tried to use the reconfigure.sh weblogic utility. While using that utility, i am getting the below exception.  The old domain is from weblogic 12.1.3.  Any clues?

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid host:port
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.jdbc.AddressList$HostPort.<init>(AddressList.java:133)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.jdbc.AddressList.setList(AddressList.java:78)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.jdbc.GridLinkRacHandler.createOnsHost(G
```

Comment: Did you researched on GridLink Data source why it is getting failed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case it was cause about the custom DataSource configured in the domain, specifically with a data source configured as GridLink without ONS configuration.
As I resolved was, first I made a backup of config.xml file, then I removed all the custom datasource references, like this:

```
  <jdbc-system-resource>
    <name>mds-soa</name>
    <target>soa_cluster,AdminServer</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/mds-soa-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
  </jdbc-system-resource>
<!--jdbc-system-resource>
    <name>OrchDS</name>
    <target>jms_cluster</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/OrchDS-1529-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
  </jdbc-system-resource-->
```

Be careful, when you reconfigure the domain, all the comments in the config.ml file was removed.
Then start the wizard for reconfig the domain until setup progress windows, just to make sure you pass all the validations and then exit. 
Add one by one until found the descriptor file who has the error.
I hope this help you.